# jQuery - Convert checkbox table to json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert a table of checkboxes into json format to save on my mongodb.

Here is my table:

[image]

I want a JSON like this or something like that:

```
Days: {
    Monday: {
        08h: true        
    },
    Saturday: {
        08h: true,
        10h: true        
    },
    Sunday: {
        08h: true,
        10h: true        
    }
}
```

Im using javascript and jQuery

I tried this function but I'm only getting the selected day instead of the array day + hour

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    serializeCustomPropertyArray: function() {
        return this.map(function() {
            return this.elements ? jQuery.makeArray(this.elements) : this;
        }).filter(function() {
            return jQuery(this).attr('data-name') &&
                (this.checked || /select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName) ||
                        /text|hidden|password|search/i.test(this.type));
        }).map(function(i, elem) {
            var val = jQuery(this).val();
            return val == null ? null : jQuery.isArray(val) ?
                jQuery.map(val, function(val, i) {
                    return { name: jQuery(elem).attr('data-name'), value: val };
                }) : { name: jQuery(elem).attr('data-name'), value: val };
        }).get();
    },
    serializeToJSON: function() {
        var objectMap = this.serializeCustomPropertyArray();
        var objectJson = new Object;
        jQuery.each(objectMap, function() {
            objectJson[this.name] = (this.value !== null) ? this.value : 'null';
        });
        return JSON.stringify(objectJson);

    }
});
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Tried using map but im geting just day selected. See my edit

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Each column should have its own name, e.g. Monday, Tuesday etc.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="08h" name="monday" />
<input type="checkbox" value="10h" name="monday" />  
[...]
<input type="checkbox" value="19h" name="saturday" />
```

Once your HTML is sorted as such, retrieving the names and values of all selected checkboxes will be easy.

```
// First we need a function to check if an object is empty (to be used later)
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// Get all checked checkboxes
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.messageCheckbox:checked');

var checked = [];

// Put names and values side-by-side in 2d array
// e.g. checked[x][0] = [name] and checked[x][1] = [value]
for(var i = 0; i < (checkedBoxes.length - 1); i++) {
    checked.push([checkedBoxes[i].name, checkedBoxes[i].value]);
}

var Days = {};

for(var j in checked) {
    // If there is not currently hour values inside Days.[day] then create an empty object so we can put an hour in
    if(isEmptyObject(Days[checked[j][0]])) Days[checked[j][0]] = {};
    // Set Days.[day].[hour] = true;
    Days[checked[j][0]][checked[j][1]] = true;
}

var finalJSON = JSON.stringify(Days);
```

Comment: this piece of code Days[checked[j][0]] = checked[j][1] overide days that has two hours

Comment: @Alberto well noticed. Edited

Comment: Still not, error: Cannot set property '08h' of undefined

Comment: @Alberto , found a few errors in my code. Should be fixed now, but I can't test with any real data.